# Validating a Dropdown form in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have this form below, using WordPress. We have a product we sell, user needs to select make and model. We are running into an issue where they are submitting the form without selecting the make and model. Trying to wrap my head around how to do this as easily as possible as I don't write code, and my developer is missing in action.

How do we ensure they cannot submit without choosing a make and model first?

Thank you.

```
<div class="span6">

    <script src="http://demosite.com/demp_data.js"></script><script src="http://demosite.com/helpers.js"></script>
    <h4>$88.99 (Discounts Available for Multiple Purchases)</h4>
    <img style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" src="http://demosite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/demo.gif" alt="" />
    <p style="line-height: 25px;">Demo Product is Made in the USA!</p>

    <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
    <img src="http://demosite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/demo.jpg" alt="" />

</div>
<div class="span6">
    <div class="box1">
        <div class="striped"></div>
        <h6 class="fontbold"><i class="icon-truck"></i> Purchase Our Product</h6>
        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

            <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" /><input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="9VAWUWSFLS6SG" />
            <table style="border: 1px solid #fff; border-collapse: separate;">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="on0" type="hidden" value="Quantity" /><span class="green">Quantity</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><select name="os0"><option value="1 Test Product">1 Test Product $88.99 USD</option><option value="2 Test Productes">2 Test Productes $221.99 USD</option><option value="3 Test Productes">3 Test Productes $223.99     USD</option></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="on1" type="hidden" value="Test Product make" /><span class="green">Test Product Make</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><select id="demo_names" name="os1"><option value="-1">Select a Test Product make</option></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="on2" type="hidden" value="Test Product model" /><span class="green">Test Product Model</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><select id="demp_models" name="os2"><option>Select a Test Product model</option></select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="on3" type="hidden" value="Watt" /><input id="watt" name="os3" type="hidden" /><input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit"     src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" type="image" /><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" />

                        Don't See Your Make and Model? <a title="Contact" href="http://www.ezTest Productswitch.com/contact/">Contact Us!</a>
                        <input name="on5" type="hidden" value="Notes" /><input id="notes" name="os5" type="hidden" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" /></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the code/plugin that generates this html form? If so post it here

Comment: Looks like standard Paypal generated code.

Comment: Aibrean is correct, this is standard PayPal checkout. Basically they choose their product and then hit Buy Now. Problem is, people aren't choosing the make and model and checking out.